# Generate maps of good quality

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I want to ask if there exists a way of laying the turtlebot in a room and it will be able to generate a map exploring alone or if I can make the maps using an application?

Thanks beforehand!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204851/generate-maps-of-good-quality/) by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2015-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's theoretically possible to let the Turtlebot drive on its own and generate its own maps, but I've found that I get much more accurate maps when I drive the robot around myself using teleop. This is detailed in the tutorial:

http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM

There are some good posts out there detailing the methodology to get more accurate maps. Some things that have worked for me are:

1. Keep the speed reasonably low, ie, the teleop defaults.
2. Make sure your laser always has a wall/feature in view, preferably a corner or something distinguishable rather than just a straight line.
3. Try to avoid in-place turns, instead taking turns while also moving forward.
4. Once you've closed loops by driving around the perimeter of the rooms, then you can start exploring more open areas.

Hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [BlitherPants](https://answers.ros.org/users/4967/blitherpants/) with karma: 504 on 2015-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on 2015-03-19**:
What is the reason of point number 3, if the Turtlebot has a good gyroscope and accelerometer already calibrated from fabric?

**Comment by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on 2015-03-19**:
With your steps I have now a good map! thanks!

**Comment by [BlitherPants](https://answers.ros.org/users/4967/blitherpants/) on 2015-03-19**:
I'm not sure exactly why. Someone once suggested that the wheels slip less that way so there's less odometry error.

**Comment by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on 2015-03-19**:
it seems to be that